# ASP pages do not load

Tags: asp.net, windows

First off, I'm not a web developer, so I might be asking the question in the wrong place. Unfortunately, I've tried searching regarding my problem but most of the issues I see are web-developer server side issues, so I'm runnig out of places to turn.

The problem: I'm trying to navigate a website, and eventually it decides to try running a ".asp" page. However, my browser just hangs (attempted Firefox and IE11), until it eventually times out. However, when I've run the same website on other machines (such as my phone), those pages load flawlessly. The fact that it's browser independent seems to suggest it's something with my local machine (Win7). I've ensured the IIS feature is turned on and the process is running, but still nothing.

The only other evidence I have is while searching for ASP tutorials, there was an example designed to show the current date/time which didn't work. The rest of the page which was straight HTML was then fine. I'm not sure if it's possible that some native binary for a scripting language isn't loading, but I'm not sure how I can debug that.

To summarise, my questions are as follows:

- What could stop an ASP page being loaded on a client machine?
- What can I do to ensure the right dependencies are present on a client machine such that it can load ASP pages?

To note, I'm not aware of anything I've installed which would affect this. The only code related program on my PC is Visual C++ Express 2013, but I'm not sure what that would do. .Net 4.5 is installed but I don't know how to tell what script the asp page is attempting to execute.

Answer (score 0):

*** What could stop an ASP page being loaded on a client machine?**

IIS?
IIS is the one responsible for parsing asp code.
IIS takes your ASP code, and then, transforms it into html code, then sends it to the client.
There might be an issue with your windows 7 computer, but there is nothing related to ASP.

*** What can I do to ensure the right dependencies are present on a client machine such that it can load ASP pages?**

There are no such dependencies. Your client makes a call to a server, which returns html code.